# Unable to import save file in Witcher 2 and 3

Tags: technical-issues, the-witcher-3, the-witcher-2

I am having a problem with importing the save files from the Witcher games. I purchased both games from GOG, but I am not able to play my save files.

I get the option of importing my save file but when I go to the *"Imperial Audience"* mission the questions are all answered as if there was no save file. The commander does not ask for Aryan whatsoever, but when I played the game again using simulate the whole mission it changed and he was asking about Aryan etc.

I want to know whether am I doing anything wrong and if my save files are in the right place C:\Users\user\Documents\Witcher 2\gamesaves. I have a lot of save files but which one should I start with? Should I start with the one after letho or the one before I speak to letho in Witcher 2?